# Getting into service uninstaller (c#)

Tags: c#, service, uninstallation

Right,

So I have a Windows service written in C#. I've already found the 'ProjectInstaller.cs' where I do some stuff, like set dependencies and service name during install.

What I'm not finding is how to hook into the uninstall process of the server.

While I know there's little workarounds here and there, such as just trashing the key from the registry, I'd like to account for a user (with local admin rights) uninstalling the service with  `sc` or `installutil.exe` - essentially, I simply want the service to write a statement to a database saying "Hey, I'm being uninstalled by bobsmith"

Possible? Doable?

Update - This is what I have in my ProjectInstaller.cs - not working...

```
namespace blahblah
{
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BeforeUninstall += new InstallEventHandler(ProjectInstaller_BeforeUninstall);
    }

    private void ProjectInstaller_BeforeUninstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
    /// do stuff...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [**ServiceInstaller**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.aspx) object in your designer (if one is not already there) and subscribe to the [**BeforeUninstall**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.beforeuninstall.aspx) event

Comment: So, this doesn't seem to be called in during the uninstall process (using installutil.exe) - I'm updating the question with the code...

Comment: I moved things around and created the installer class manually. Seems to be working now. Strange that it wasn't called with the generic ProjectInstaller that VS lets you add...